# JavaScript call a function who's name is a in string for a function in a anonymous scope

Tags: javascript, function, closures

Is this doable in javascript ? I try to call the function who's name is in the variable named "name" (sorry!). That function is not in the global scope.

```
(function () {
    var myFunc, name;

    myFunc = function(){
        alert("Hi!");
    };
    name = "myFunc";
    //myFunc();  // work

    (name)();   // do not work
    this[name]();   // do not work

})();
```

Note: I have a jsfiddle entry [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B7QVj/5/)

Comment: You almost certainly want to use an object here.

Comment: Could you give me an example ? Do not forget that my case is reduced to show only the problem i'm dealing with.

Comment: Why can't you do name = myFunc and then name()?

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan: Because `name` is a string and is probably coming from somewhere else.

Comment: AbhinavRanjan : Sometime myFunc is not defined so I can not have a reference to it.

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan You're right I should have put name = "myFunc" before defining the body of myFunc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an object for the "local scope" like there is for the global scope.  You can (and should) make your own object to hold your functions:

```
(function () {
    var name = "myFunc";

    var funcs = {
        myFunc: function(){
            alert("Hi!");
        }
    };

    funcs[name]();
})();
```

Comment: The answer from @Doorknob of Snow is good and got an upvote but I accept your answer because it's more concise and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

```
eval(name)();
```

`eval` is not ***always*** evil. It does have its uses.

If you really don't like eval, try storing your variables in an object instead:

```
(function () {
    var vars = {};

    vars.myFunc = function(){
        alert("Hi!");
    };

    vars.name = "myFunc";
    //vars.myFunc();  // work

    vars[vars.name]();    
})();
```

Comment: eval always call from the global scope... I cannot use it.. i think ! :-)

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMartin I didn't comment about eval... anyway, I'm trying to say, `eval` is not always global scope. Try putting the eval code and it will work.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMartin: `eval` actually runs in the scope in which it was called (that's why it can be dangerous!).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
myFunc = function(){
```

to

```
this.myFunc = function(){
```

then this will work:

```
this[name]();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B7QVj/6/

Comment: Right !! Thanks ! But why this can not see myFunc the way I declared it in my example ?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this.  In this case, `this` will actually be `window` (because the function is being called without a context), so `this.myFunc` is just making `myFunc` global.  (plus it won't work in "strict mode")

Comment: oh... Rocket Hazmat you're right. ( this === window) is true. Again I would have thought otherwise... I'm in a anonymous block... Why is this === window ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMartin: Because `this` is the context of the running function.  When your anonymous function runs it has a context of `null`.  When a function has a `null` context, it becomes `window`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this `the value of this is not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object`.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat : I learn everyday. Thanks for answering my question.